# How to implement Push Notification in Windows 8 App using C# with Sharepoint 2010/ 13?

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, windows-8, push-notification, sharepoint-2013

I have a specific requirement to implement push notification in Windows 8 App using C# with Sharepoint 2010. What I am able to find are couple of links using Windows Phone and sharepoint but none using Windows 8 + sharepoint 2010/ 13. Is this possible is yes then how can I achieve this. Please share some links.

Links that I have found:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163784.aspx#BKMK_ServerSideSolution
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163784.aspx

Comment: What do you need to push, exactly? There's lots of ways to get at SharePoint data (especially SP2013), so having more details would improve the answers you get.

Comment: Push notifications in Windows 8 very closely related to WP7. You should be able to follow instructions in the link you provided and make adjustments specific to Win8 i.e. xml format, headers, etc.

Comment: @Denis: My prime focus is on SharePoint 2010. I am able to find the links for SharePoint 2013 but not for 2010. So can you help me to get Push Notification on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @CBono: Actually I need Push Notification on SharePoint 2010 because there is a specific requirement that if there is some new data entered in a ShapePoint list like Announcement then it should be prompted immediately to the user of this app as Notification.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not an expert in SharePoint, so I can't help you with that. I was just pointing out that if you can find solution that implements push notifications for WP7 using SharePoint 2010 it should be pretty easy to adopt it to Win8.